# Directus custom interface

Tags: directus

Can someone explain normally, how i can create directus interface extension? I readed docs, but i didn't understand anything from there. It just says that we can use vue js, but not a word about the implementation itself. I've been sitting for 4 hours and I can't find a normal source. The question is: Сan someone suggest what ш need to learn or read in order to be able to write interface extensions?

Tried:

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/interfaces.html
Dimitrov Adrian github repos..

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest reading all of the extensions documentation from the start.

The page I've linked explains how to begin creating an extension, the page you have linked is a specific *type* of extension.

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/creating-extensions.html

Comment: Yes, i know. I specially linked this page, becouse i need corectly interface extension. I already readed all docs from directus. I'm interested just in coding method, how i can do this interface.vue, how i want and were i can read or learn infos about it

Answer (score -1):

1. in the extension itself generate the interface - npm init directus-extension@latest
2. then use the npm run build command and set the path package.json file
3. change the interface name.